# How do I get the same JSON response I get in development, in production?

Tags: jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using jQuery-ui's autocomplete on a search form. In development the request hits my index page which returns a JSON response:

The response looks like so:

> [{"id":0,"listing_id":0,"category_id":0,"title":"Natural Woven Linen
>   Ring Sling","description":"This natural woven linen sling is perfect
>   for keeping you and baby comfortable in any climate. With light
>   comfort, it will conform to you and your child\u0026#39;s body and
>   become softer over time.\nSlings are a great way to keep your baby
>   close and your hands free.\nWearing your baby increases bonding by
>   encouraging skin to skin contact and closeness with parents and
>   caregivers. Baby slings mimic the womb environment, making baby feel
>   safe and secure. Baby\u0026#39;s needs are easily met when held close,
>   which means less crying. Baby slings are great for discreet
>   breastfeeding no matter where you are. \nThis sling is suitable for
>   babies between 7-35 Pounds.\nBe sure to exercise caution when wearing
>   your baby.\n*Keep baby\u0026#39;s face visible at all
>   times.\n*Practice wearing your sling before putting baby
>   inside.\n*Avoid any unsafe activities while wearing your baby, such
>   as:\nSmoking, drinking hot drinks, running, exercising, cooking, or
>   drinking
>   alcohol.","price":"65.00","currency_code":"CAD","quantity":1,"tags":["sling
>   rings","ring sling","toddler","newborn","natural linen","woven
>   wrap","baby carrier","woven sling","babywearing","baby wrap","baby
>   sling"],"category_path":["Bags and
>   Purses"],"taxonomy_path":["Accessories","Baby Accessories","Baby
>   Carriers \u0026 Wraps"],"materials":["aluminum rings","european
>   linen","cotton
>   thread"],"featured_rank":null,"url":"https://www.etsy.com/listing/272579256/natural-woven-linen-ring-sling?utm_source=etsyinventorymerger\u0026utm_medium=api\u0026utm_campaign=api","views":19,"num_favorers":0,"shipping_template_id":6281647,"shipping_profile_id":null,"images":["https://img1.etsystatic.com/135/0/6276910/il_170x135.987731269_rwab.jpg","https://img1.etsystatic.com/139/0/6276910/il_170x135.987731277_1q29.jpg","https://img1.etsystatic.com/140/0/6276910/il_170x135.987731279_q5lv.jpg"],"created_at":"2016-03-28T20:01:41.722Z","updated_at":"2016-03-28T20:04:52.721Z"},{"id":18,"listing_id":269532744,"category_id":269532744,"title":"Woven
>   Cotton Whimsical Waves Ring Sling","description":"This sling is
>   lightweight, yet sturdy and made from 100% cotton. The shoulder is
>   sewn to comfortably keep your arms free and baby\u0026#39;s weight
>   evenly distributed. Great for any climate and perfect for any outfit.
>   \n\nSlings are a great way to keep your baby close and your hands
>   free.\nWearing your baby increases bonding by encouraging skin to skin
>   contact and closeness with parents and caregivers. Baby slings mimic
>   the womb environment, making baby feel safe and secure.
>   Baby\u0026#39;s needs are easily met when held close, which means less
>   crying. Baby slings are great for discreet breastfeeding no matter
>   where you are. \nThis sling is suitable for babies between 7-35
>   Pounds.\nBe sure to exercise caution when wearing your baby.\n*Keep
>   baby\u0026#39;s face visible at all times.\n*Practice wearing your
>   sling before putting baby inside.\n*Avoid any unsafe activities while
>   wearing your baby, such as:\nSmoking, drinking hot drinks, running,
>   exercising, cooking, or drinking
>   alcohol.","price":"65.00","currency_code":"CAD","quantity":1,"tags":["new
>   mom gift","baby shower gift","newborn sling","baby wrap","ring sling
>   tail","woven cotton sling","woven ring sling","baby carrier","ring
>   sling","canadian made"],"category_path":["Bags and
>   Purses"],"taxonomy_path":["Accessories","Baby Accessories","Baby
>   Carriers \u0026 Wraps"],"materials":["cotton","aluminum rings","cotton
>   thread"],"featured_rank":1,"url":"https://www.etsy.com/listing/269532744/woven-cotton-whimsical-waves-ring-sling?utm_source=etsyinventorymerger\u0026utm_medium=api\u0026utm_campaign=api","views":42,"num_favorers":3,"shipping_template_id":6281647,"shipping_profile_id":null,"images":["https://img1.etsystatic.com/115/0/6276910/il_170x135.927557949_lp3o.jpg","https://img1.etsystatic.com/113/0/6276910/il_170x135.927557945_8km2.jpg","https://img1.etsystatic.com/117/0/6276910/il_170x135.927557953_nyef.jpg","https://img0.etsystatic.com/112/0/6276910/il_170x135.927814742_9wo0.jpg","https://img1.etsystatic.com/127/0/6276910/il_170x135.927557973_223q.jpg"],"created_at":"2016-03-28T20:01:45.104Z","updated_at":"2016-03-28T20:04:56.129Z"}]

This is my controller:

```
def index
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json do
      @etsy_products = EtsyProduct.search(params[:term])
      render json: @etsy_products, status: :ok, message: 'Success'
    end
  end
```

end

My script receives the return response and formats it accordingly:

```
$ ->
  $('#etsy_products_search').autocomplete(
    minLength: 0
    source: '/'
    focus: (event, ui) ->
      $('#etsy_products_search').val ui.item.title
      false
    select: (event, ui) ->
      $('#etsy_products_search').val ui.item.title
      $('#etsy_products_search-description').html ui.item.description
      false
  ).autocomplete('instance')._renderItem = (ul, item) ->
    $('<li>')
      .attr({'title': item.description, 'data-toggle': 'tooltip', 'data-thumbnail': item.images[0], 'data-etsy-url': item.url})
      .append(item.title).appendTo ul
```

My development log shows this:

```
Started GET "/?term=woven" for ::1 at 2016-03-28 17:16:49 -0400
Processing by HomeController#index as JSON
  Parameters: {"term"=>"woven"}
  EtsyProduct Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "etsy_products".* FROM "etsy_products" WHERE (title ILIKE '%woven%')
Completed 200 OK in 18ms (Views: 13.6ms | ActiveRecord: 2.5ms)
```

I deployed by app, then tested it in production. The JSON response is empty, and my production log looks like so:

```
I, [2016-03-28T17:19:13.552941 #25285]  INFO -- : Started GET "/?term=woven" for (ip) at 2016-03-28 17:19:13 -0400
I, [2016-03-28T17:19:13.558963 #25285]  INFO -- : Processing by HomeController#index as JSON
I, [2016-03-28T17:19:13.559220 #25285]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"term"=>"woven"}
D, [2016-03-28T17:19:13.565312 #25285] DEBUG -- :   EtsyProduct Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "etsy_products".* FROM "etsy_products" WHERE (title ILIKE '%woven%')
I, [2016-03-28T17:19:13.566088 #25285]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 7ms (Views: 2.0ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
```

If I go into console on the Production server, and run my search script it returns all the entries as it should. The trouble seems to be when it passes the response back to the request. It comes back empty. I'm sure it's something stupid that I've overlooked, but I can't seem to find the right answer on Google, or, (which is more likely) I'm asking the wrong question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was completely on the wrong track. The issue wasn't with the response, but actually with the database. You see, when I checked to ensure the database had records, I was doing the standard "rails c" method on the production server. I'm using a rake task to collect records from an API and write them to the database. So long story short, the rake task was actually writing to a development database that was on my server, and not to the production. When I ran "rails c" it was giving me access to that database and not to the production database. Urgh! Still a lot to learn. Hopefully this will help another newb in the future in case they get walled like I did.